"openssl genpkey" can't use option "-cipher des3"
Trying to create RSA key via openssl:
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -cipher des3 -outform PEM -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048 -out myCA.pem
This output:

genpkey: Use -help for summary.

If I remove -cipher des3, then it works, the cmd become:
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -outform PEM -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048 -out myCA.pem
But the man page has this option:

The questions are:

why -cipher des3 option is not supported, and how to fix it?
does it matter if I don't add -cipher option?


The option is not documented as -cipher algorithm but as -cipher. This means it should not be -cipher des3 but instead -des3. This can also be seen in the examples which are part of the documentation. To cite:

openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out key.pem -aes-128-cbc -pass pass:hello


In this case AES-128-CBC is used instead of DES3. This is the more appropriate choice today, since DES3 is no longer considered adequately secure.

They should improve that man page.

@Eric: feel free to provide a bug report or (even better) make a suggestion on how to improve it. See https://openssl-library.org/community/index.html#bugs on how to contribute this way.

issue added on github: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/26089

BTW, do you happen to know what is the -sha256 option from cmd: openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout tg.key -x509 -days 3660 -out tg.pem \   -subj "/C=HK/ST=Hong Kong/L=Queen/O=E/CN=<your_host_or_ip>", is it -digest ?

I suppose it is, since it's the only option with underscore, from man openssl-req.

@Eric: yes, sha256 is a message digest. See also openssl list -digest-algorithms
